# Comparing dates results with Doctrine

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I wrote an api call with form builder which creates two date fields. The idea is to choose two dates and return results from db of data in that date range.

I can't find where the problem is but I think the syntax in query builder is not right.

I don't get any errors just an empty array.

Here is an api call from service

```
public function getTransaction()
{
    $result = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.date >= :from')
        ->andWhere('a.date <= :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('to',   $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->orderBy('p.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    return $result;
}
```

My controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('dateFrom', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => array(
                'dateFrom' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),
            )))
        ->add('dateTo', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => array(
                'dateTo' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),
            )))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn-link form-btn'
        ]))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $transactions = $this->get('app')->getTransaction();
    }

    return $this->render('default/finance.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView(), 't' => $t)
    );
}
```

and my twig view

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Info</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for a in t %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ a.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.user }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.info }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>`
```

Comment: `'dateTo' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),` These are set, however, `$this->get('app')->getTransaction()` does not receive your `To` and `From` dates. Should you not do `$this->get('app')->getTransaction($from, $to)` and the `getTransaction` do `->setParameter('from', $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` (and same for `'to'`) instead ?

Comment: Also, did you ask [the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304972/doctrine-query-with-date-range) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your code your `getTransaction` repo function is not receiving the `$to` and `$from` DateTime objects it should be receiving. Update that function like so:

```
public function getTransaction(DateTime $from, DateTime $to) : Collection
{
    $result = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.date >= :from')
        ->andWhere('a.date <= :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('to',   $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->orderBy('p.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    return $result;
}
```

And your call should include the parameters now required, like so:

```
$transactions = $this->get('app')->getTransaction($from, $to);
```

I'm not quite sure what's available with `FormBuilder`, so guessing the full function call would be:

```
$transactions = $this->get('app')->getTransaction(
    $form->get('dateFrom')->getValue(),
    $form->get('dateTo')->getValue(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should specify what error you get.

Anyway, I'm not sure but I would try to replace all `p.date` with `Date` in your query builder, since you are using `SELECT AS`. Also `DATE` is reserved keyword in MySQL and you should replace it with something else.