# Doctrine - query with date range

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine, query-builder

I wrote a query that I can call within my form to select date range and to return all database data in that range.

The api call works fine but when I set date parameters it returns an empty result.

```
$date = new \Datetime();

    $result = $this->getMyRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.date >= :from')
        ->andWhere('a.date <= :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('to',   $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->orderBy('a.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    return $result;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing dates results with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291954/comparing-dates-results-with-doctrine) - Flagged as looks like asked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you have used `format` in your `from` and `to` dates, which you don't need to. Also, I have noticed that the same `$date` has been used for both `from` and `to`. I am sure you didn't mean to use like that.

Replace this,

```
 ->setParameter('from', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
 ->setParameter('to',   $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

with this,

```
$dateFrom = new \Datetime();
$dateFrom->setDate(2017, 1, 31);

$dateTo = new \Datetime();
$dateTo->setDate(2017, 12, 31);

->setParameter('from', $dateFrom )
->setParameter('to',   $dateTo)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.